# global variables in different functions

Tags: jquery, html

One thing I think i will never get about variables is the following thing.

I have a hover function like this:

```
var $thisId = $(this).attr('id');
function bindHover() {
    $("#wrapper img").hover( function() {
        console.log($thisId);
    });
}
```

The console.log gives me `undefined`. When im declaring the variable in between the function it works. Now the question, if I want `$(this).attr('id')` in all different function I have in my js. What can I do that I dont have to write a new variable in every function?

Comment: to make a variable global its $.variable not $variable

Comment: Assign it in the scope of top level object in your application

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');` can also be written as `this.id`.

Comment: What is $(this) outside of the hover function?

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` must be undefined. as it probably looks for window.

Comment: `this` and `$(this)` refer to nothing outside that function

Comment: Any variable can be made global in JavaScript by attaching it as a property of the window object. E.g. `window.foo = 'bar';`

Comment: that means i have to declare the `$(this).attr('id')`in every function! to get the value of the id which is currently hovered?

Comment: @TedMosby, yes. If you want other functions to know which element is the currently hovered element, you'd need to add the `$(this).attr('id')` into your hover function. Otherwise, use the `id` as a param for those functions (which can get messy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $thisId = $(this).attr('id');
```

This line will be ran ***once***, `$thisId` will be assigned a value, and the code will move on.

So, when your `bindHover` function is called, and the handler is assigned, it'll use whatever value `$thisId` had when it was assigned.

You need to get the `id` from inside the handler, so that `this` is the element you want.

```
function bindHover() {
    $("#wrapper img").hover( function() {
        //console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        console.log(this.id); // it's shorter :-)
    });
}
```

Comment: okay, but what to do if i have a lots of elements and want my code keep small and dont want to write `$(this).attr('id')`about 25 times!

Comment: @TedMosby in that case you can write `this.id`.. Its shorter..:)

Comment: okay thanks, but at least one question! i always thought to declare my variable as `var $blabla` not `var blabla` has no difference? correct?

Comment: @TedMosby: The dollar sign, `$`, is just a character, it has no special meaning in JavaScript.  It's not like PHP where all variables need to start with `$`.  `var abc = 123; var $abc = 456;  var a$bc = 789;` are all valid variables in JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for your help guys! i got it now! edit: i guess its just for myself knowing its a jquery variable huh?

Comment: @TedMosby: People usually prepend `$` to variables in JavaScript to show that it's a jQuery object, or at least that's what I do.  Example: `var $header = $('#header');  var footer = 'this is some text';`.  So, I know that `$header` is a jQuery object, and `footer` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $thisId; // create the var in global space
function bindHover() {
  $("#wrapper img").hover( function() {
    $thisId = $(this).attr('id'); // set global var in local space
    console.log($thisId); // global var displays local $(this) id
  });
  console.log($thisId); // global var retains locally defined value until set again
}
```